# java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, button, audio, jframe

I am using netbeans 6.8 .If a sound file is playing, a button on the jframe wont work while the sound file is playing. The user should still be able to press the button while it is playing. 
I tried to find it but the codes are very complex.
Use `Main implements runnable{}`
Multithread this problem.

Comment: What havwe you've tried so far? Give some code please.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are playing a sound on the [Event despatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Any long running tasks should not be run on this since, as you've seen, it'll lock the gui.

Answer (score 2):

Try [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). There are [Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

You can either implement thread yourself or use higher level tools like

1. Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(command)
2. java.util.Timer: new Timer().schedule(task, 0)
3. SwingWorker (asm mentioned by @user802421

Here is how you can run task asynchronously using your own thread:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // write here your code
    }
}.start();
```