# SwingWorker get a result

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a SwingWorker, which does some computations in the background (these actions are situated in the overridden `doInBackground()` method). So, I also use the `execute()` method to begin the computations. How I can get the result of these computations when they are finished?

Comment: It's no code  now. Now I think about how to connect SwingWorker and my model and view of MVC-structure of application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `done` method - that method will be called when the work is complete.  Oracle has a comprehensive tutorial here: [Improve Application Performance With SwingWorker in Java SE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/swingworker-137249.html)

Also see another SO question: [How do I use SwingWorker in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java)

You can call `get` to retrieve the results but if the worker isn't done the thread will block until the worker is done.  That means if you call `get` from the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) your GUI will be unresponsive if the worker isn't done.  You can call `isDone` to determine if the worker has completed.

Finally, you can attach a property change listener to be notified of the worker's progress, including when it completes its task.  The first link I posted gives an example of that.

Comment: thx! I will try it! mayby there are some common patterns of using SwingWorker in MVC?

Comment: @dizpers, yes - the Swing Worker and the work it can be decoupled from the UI. Attach a listener to the worker and update the UI when the worker is complete. You can also fire a `PropertyChangeEvent` to recognize intermediate progress, if you want your UI to keep the user apprised of progress.

Comment: where is get() officially documented?

Comment: @jj_, `get()` is a `SwingWorker` method and as such is documented in the API.  Here's the link to the method in the Java 8 API:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get--

Answer (score 4):

You can override `done()` and/or `process()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513) and [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata).

Comment: I need exactly return statement. What will happened, if I just call doInBackground method of my worker?

Comment: It'll just run, possibly blocking the EDT. Instead, instantiate the worker and `execute()` it, as shown in the examples.

Comment: @dizpers _What will happened, I just call doInBackground_ hell breaking loose ;-) As always when you do something **terribly wrong** - simply stick to the usage as extensively explained in both the java doc and the tutorial chapter on concurrency in Swing