# How to open a hidden jframe from another jframe by clicking a button

Tags: java, swing

I have a Jframe called TabletAddDetails and when I click back button the Jframe TabletAddDetails will be hidden and open Jframe Tablet. There is a button in Jframe Tablet open Jframe  TabletAddDetails . Is there any way that I could open the same previously hidden Jframe TabletAddDetails instead of a completely new instance of Jframe  TabletAddDetails so that my progress bar update will not get lost when I come back.

Here is the code for back Buttom in Jframe  TabletAddDetails

```
JButton btnBack = new JButton("BACK");
        btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try
                {

                Tablet tab=new Tablet();
                tab.setVisible(true);
                tab.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                tab.setResizable(false);
                tab.setTitle("Tablet"); 
                setVisible(false);
                                try {
                    tab.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("img/icon.png")));
                }
                catch (IOException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }

                }
                 catch (Exception e) 
                {

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage()); 
                    }
            }
        });
```

Here is the code for Button TabletAddDetails in Jframe Tablet

```
JButton btnDetails = new JButton("TabletAddDetails");
        btnDetails.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try
                {

                TabletAddDetails tabadd=new TabletAddDetails();
                tabadd.setVisible(true);
                tabadd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                tabadd.setResizable(false);
                tabadd.setTitle("Tablet Add Details"); 
                setVisible(false);
                                    try {
                    tabadd.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("img/icon.png")));
                }
                catch (IOException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
                                }
                 catch (Exception e) 
                {

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage()); 
                    }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any way I just found a solution to update the progress bar even if I open another instance of Jframe TabletAddDetails . Now when I come back the progress bar update will be continued . I implement it in a quite easy way . I have a time taking function which is done by using [swingworker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java) . Previously I implement the swingworker in the same Jframe TabletAddDetails . Now what I do is very simple , just make another class in src folder and copy all the codes in the swingworker to it and call that class when I press the buttion in Jframe TabletAddDetails.

Here since the data manipulation and update of progress bar is done by  another separate class (ie the Model in [MVC](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2013/07/20/the-mvc-pattern-implemented-with-java-swing/)) which is linked to your Jframe (View in [MVC](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2013/07/20/the-mvc-pattern-implemented-with-java-swing/)), so even if you close and come back to same Jframe the functional part will still connected to it. So I hardly recommend to follow [MVC](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2013/07/20/the-mvc-pattern-implemented-with-java-swing/) when implementing java swing projects.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) in your new jFrame and pass a reference to the parent jFrame.

```
void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    parent.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a reference to Tablet as argument in the constructor of TabletAddDetails

```
        private JFrame myTablet;

        public TabletAddDetails(JFrame parent) {
                 myTablet = parent;
        }
```

...

```
        JButton btnBack = new JButton("BACK");
        btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    try {

                        myTablet.setVisible(true);
                        // Maybe you have already set this in original instance   
                        // myTablet.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        // myTablet.setResizable(false);
                        // myTablet.setTitle("Tablet"); 
                        setVisible(false);
```

...

Comment: ? That code does exactly what you ask. I don't know what you mean. Maybe it doesn't work with the rest of your app.