# repaint() not calling paintComponent()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent, repaint

First of all, please don't burn me at the stake for creating a question while others with similar names and content exist. I looked through them all, but found no solution.

Calling repaint() absolutely does not call paintComponent(), no matter what I seem to try. Here's **all the code related** to the problem:

```
 @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {//User clicks on play button, creates a new Level object. Level extends JPanel.
     if(isOnPlayButton(e.getPoint())){
       GameState.setState(GameState.INGAME);
       Level l = new Level(2);
       l.setVisible(true);
       Tetris.getWindow().setContentPane(l);
       Soundtrack.updateAudio();
       System.out.println("Level panel created and content pane set");
     }
   }
```

As intended, "Level panel created and content pane set" is printed to console.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Level extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

  private final int levelNum;

  public Level(int levelNum){
    this.levelNum = levelNum;

    this.repaint();//Although this should work in the constructor, how about a Timer that repaints for confirmation?
    new Timer(2*1000, this).start();
  }

  @Override 
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    g.drawImage(Tetris.getTexture("LevelBackdrop.png"), 0, 0, null);
    System.out.println("paintComponent - level painted");
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 0));
    g.drawString("2", 355, 55);
  }

  public int getLevelNum() {
    return levelNum;
  }

  public double getGravity(){
    return levelNum/4;
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.repaint();
    System.out.println("Timer repainting");
  }

}
```

"paintComponent - level painted" is never printed. "Timer repainting" prints out every 2 seconds, as expected.

Comment: can you just remove the timer try it, and remove that repaint() from the Level Constructor

Comment: I suggest Swingworkers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java

Comment: I recommend posting an [mcve]. As it is currently, one cannot reproduce what you are experiencing and there doesn't seem to be anything obvious (at least that I see) from the posted code.

Comment: "remove the timer try it, and remove that repaint()." No, that did not work.

Comment: "I recommend posting an Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."
It's hard to post a minimal **and** verifiable example. Do you want me to post all the classes? All the code?

Comment: "I suggest Swingworkers." I don't completely understand this. Where and how would I use it? Are you sure that this is the problem?

Comment: `Do you want me to post all the classes? All the code?` No - that's not 'minimal'. The point is 2 fold: 1. You are asking volunteers for help - posting excessive code will most likely require too much time for any volunteer to take 2. Often the problem is revealed during the process of creating an mcve (and that's what debugging is all about)

Comment: To continue on copeg's suggestion, create a single frame with a panel and a button. Override the panel's `paintComponent` method and have the button call repaint on the panel. Do this from scratch (takes ~1 min). Compare the results and the code. Once you find the thing that causes the problem, if you didn't solve it yourself by now, post the modified MCVE and we'll help you.

Comment: @copeg, I agree . HelpMe no offence but  just  be more precise about the problem,  review your code, debug till finding what's wrong or at least limit the area of suspicious code. www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmlXU4uK5rA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what is the actual size of the `level` object when the repaint is called? If it is zero height and width, the `paintComponent` method will not be called. Since you never call `setPreferredSize(...)`, I think this might be the reason.

If this does not solve your problem, overwrite the `repaint()` method in `Level` and break on it to see what it actually does (requires jdk installation).

Comment: If you have a question ask it in the comments. Don't post questions as an answer.

Comment: I think you're right. This might be the problem. Near my call to repaint(), I did "System.out.println(this.getSize().getWidth() + "  :  " + this.getSize().getHeight());" And both the width and height came out to 0.0
Unfortunately, setPrefferedSize() doesn't do anything to fix that.

Comment: I used setSize() and it worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH =)

Comment: I haven't use swing stuff for a while, but I remember that `setPreferredSize()` is usually a better option. It would take a while to figure out why it does not work for you though.