# Is there a way to increase the progress bar value at a specific pace while not monitoring progress of a task?

Tags: java, swing

I just wanted to add a progress bar to my program for aesthetics and not actually monitoring a task progress. I'm using the Jframe progress bar.

```
for(int i=0; i<=100;i++){


  jProgressBar1.setValue(i);

}
```

im currently using this code but it fills up the progress bar immediately. Is there a way to slow it down without using Thread.sleep?
Thanks.

Comment: yes, add Thread.sleep to it and most importantly execute the code on a background thread.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `Thread.sleep()`? That is actually the solution.

Comment: @luk2302 how would i do this in a background thread? when i do it in the main thread, it pauses the entire program

Comment: `setIndeterminate(true)`?

Comment: use this good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144967/how-to-asynchronous-trigger-jprogressbar/48147638#48147638), and by changing `Thread.sleep(value_in_millisec);` you can control the `JProgressBar` progress delay.