# can't get sequential behavior Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, sequential

I wanted to create a "Please wait" animation while, my algorithm is running, that's what I did

```
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                res.add(image);
                res.setVisible(true);

                String input = txtFind.getText();
                Engine engine = new Engine(input);
                engine.generate();
                List<String> s = engine.getList();

                res.remove(image);

                s.forEach(x -> {
                    JLabel txt = new JLabel(x);
                    res.add(txt);
                });

            }
```

The idea behind is to display my gif animation when I click on a button, then call my heavy function "generate", once done, I remove my animation and display the results,

However, Im getting another behavior : res becomes visible but without the animation, and then after some seconds (while generate is running) it displays the results.. 
I noticed that if I remove all my "res.add(txt)" and remove also "res.remove(image)" I still don't get the right behavior as it displays animation only after generate() finishes running and not at the same time.. It feels like the function is not runned sequentially

Comment: You don't appear to be running the long-running code, the `engine.generate();`, in a background thread. By not doing this, you're running this code on the Swing event thread, blocking this thread and freezing your GUI. Best to fix this. Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for details on how to use a SwingWorker to help you do this correctly and for the details on Swing threading rules.

Comment: Side note: never use a MouseListener on a JButton in this way, but instead use an ActionListener. Otherwise if you later decide to disable the button, the listener will not be disabled automatically in parallel.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh okay thank you I'm pretty new at creating graphics in Java ahah

Comment: @MehdiZayene You can look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079885/java-loading-gif-freeze-while-processing-data "example") too for publishing some sort of progress.