# Is there a way to use threads to display different images in the same Frame?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, frame

I'll start by saying that i'm kinda new to Java, so if i'm doing something obviously wrong don't insult me please...

I am having trouble finding a way to display different images in different positions in the same JFrame/Canvas, I've tried using Graphics, but if I write it as `public void run(Graphics g)` then `thread.start()` will not recognize it as its run method and nothing will happen.

In summary I can't find a way to use thread's run method to diplay multiple different images in the same Frame, hope I've been clear enough (if not just ask me what I meant).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us your code or at least provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How did you display one image in one position in the same JFrame/Canvas?

Comment: Why do you want to use threads at all instead of main application thread?

Comment: Because I've been requested to do so

Comment: *I am having trouble finding a way to display different images in different positions* - define "different positions". The basic approach would be to create an ImageIcon and then create a JLabel using this Icon and then add the label to the frame. You choose the appropriate layout manager to display each of the labels.

Comment: If you want to use Threads, then use a `Swing Worker`. The SwingWorker will make it easy to create the Thread and "publish" each image as you read it. Read the section frmo the Swing tutorial on [Tasks That Have Interim Results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html)

Comment: Consider a thread safe `Model` that hold all the information that `View` needs. Have a thread or threads that modifies the `Model` and have `View` listen to changes in `Model`. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58528000/3992939)