# SwingWorker get() freezing interface

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, swingworker

I am using SwingWorker to get some long running database calls done in the background. Right before executing the SwingWorker I launch a jpanel with label to inform user that the app is doing some background work. The problem is that if I use the SwingWorker get() method to fetch the results of the long running operations, my jpanel freezes and nothing gets displayed. If I don't use the get() method, the jpanel appears normally.

Can you please let me know what I may be doing wrong? I already spend hours on this without figuring out why. The SwingWorker gets executed after all jpanel creation is done, I don't understand why it's getting hang.

Thanks a lot!

**Function that creates jpanel and starts SwingWorker:**

```
private void snapshotOldVariables() {

    JFrame loadingJFrame = new JFrame();
    LoadingJPanel loadingJPanel = new LoadingJPanel();

    Dimension d1 = new Dimension();
    d1.setSize(500, 500);
    loadingJFrame.setResizable(false);
    loadingJFrame.setMinimumSize(d1);
    loadingJFrame.setTitle("Loading...");
    loadingJFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    loadingJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    loadingJFrame.add(loadingJPanel);
    loadingJFrame.setVisible(true);

    loadingJPanel.updateStatus("Creating snapshot of values...");

    MySwingWorker worker = new MySwingWorker(tableRows, selectedItems);
    worker.execute();

    GMSnapshotVO snap = null;
    try {
        snap = worker.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    loadingJPanel.updateStatus("Complete");
    loadingJFrame.dispose();


    productIds = snap.getProductIds();
    oldLocationIds = snap.getOldLocationIds();
    oldStatusIds = snap.getOldStatusIds();

}
```

**Screenshot of jpanel freezed while function waits for worker.get():**
[image]

**Function with commented worker.get() code block:**
    private void snapshotOldVariables() {

```
    JFrame loadingJFrame = new JFrame();
    LoadingJPanel loadingJPanel = new LoadingJPanel();

    Dimension d1 = new Dimension();
    d1.setSize(500, 500);
    loadingJFrame.setResizable(false);
    loadingJFrame.setMinimumSize(d1);
    loadingJFrame.setTitle("Loading...");
    loadingJFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    loadingJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    loadingJFrame.add(loadingJPanel);
    loadingJFrame.setVisible(true);

    loadingJPanel.updateStatus("Creating snapshot of values...");

    MySwingWorker worker = new MySwingWorker(tableRows, selectedItems);
    worker.execute();

    /* COMMENT STARTS HERE
    GMSnapshotVO snap = null;
    try {
        snap = worker.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    loadingJPanel.updateStatus("Complete");
    loadingJFrame.dispose();

    productIds = snap.getProductIds();
    oldLocationIds = snap.getOldLocationIds();
    oldStatusIds = snap.getOldStatusIds();
    COMMENT ENDS HERE */

}
```

**Screenshot of jpanel not freezed and appearing correctly:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you should not call `SwingWorker`'s `get()` method directly from UI thread unless you are sure it is done processing. Instead you should call it inside overriden `MySwingWorker.done()`, where you can be sure that background task finished executing.

It is not relevant, that all `JPanel` creation is done before blocking as Swing still needs its main UI thread for repainting and updating UI and to stay responsive. By calling `get()` you are blocking it.

From UI thread you should just call `execute()` and all the processing of results (`productIds = snap.getProductIds(); oldLocationIds = snap.getOldLocationIds(); oldStatusIds = snap.getOldStatusIds();` in your case) should be done inside `done()` callback.

A simple example is available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java).

In your case it should go something like this:

```java
//inside MySwingWorker
@Override
protected void done() {
    try {
        System.out.println("My long running database process is done. Now I can update UI without blocking/freezing it.");
        GMSnapshotVO snap = get();
        loadingJPanel.updateStatus("Complete");
        loadingJFrame.dispose();
        productIds = snap.getProductIds();
        oldLocationIds = snap.getOldLocationIds();
        oldStatusIds = snap.getOldStatusIds();
        //..do other stuff with ids
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.